# how can I solve the brew link wget /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES not writable problem? chown chmod did not work

Tags: homebrew, wget

I installed wget with `brew install wget`, and tried to link with `brew link wget`. Then I got `Error: Could not symlink share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/wget-gnulib.mo /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.`

Trying `sudo chown -R jinglin:admin /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES` and `sudo chmod a+rwx /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES` did not help.

Anyone had the same problem and know how to solve? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the folder has rwx on all, but what about the file system?

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx   4 jinglin  admin   128 25 Jul 08:22 LC_MESSAGES` is this what you are asking?

Comment: thank you Timothy, maybe that is the problem, maybe with Mac Big Sur the file system is read only, that is why chmod/chown did not work? Still then I need to find a solution how to make the brew link wget work.

Comment: Check if the filesystem is mounted as read-only first, if it is, you need to mount it properly.

Comment: ok, I will have a look, thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

In case someone run into the same issue, this line solved my problem:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`